# Cannot figure out why my code is not working

Tags: c

I've been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code for days; I can't seem to find it. If statements confuse me quite a bit, so I'm thinking I messed those up, but still not sure. All I know is that I'm super stumped and would love all of the help I can get.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// function  main begins program execution
int main(void)
{
    int numberOfDays = 0;
    float numberOfMiles = 0;
    float milesCharge = 0;
    float milesTotal = 0;
    float total = 0;
    float subtotal = 0;
    float tax = 0;

    do {
        printf("%s", "How many days was car rented?\t");
        scanf("%d", &numberOfDays);
    } while (numberOfDays < 1 );

    do {
        printf("%s", "How many miles were driven?\t");
        scanf("%d", &numberOfMiles);
    } while (numberOfMiles > 1);

    if (numberOfMiles > 1 || numberOfMiles < 200) {
        milesTotal = numberOfMiles * .40;
    } else {
        milesTotal = numberOfMiles * .35;
    }

    subtotal = milesTotal + numberOfDays * 15;
    tax = subtotal * .06;
    total = tax + subtotal; 

    printf("\nSubtotal:\t\t\t$%.2f\n", subtotal);
    printf("Tax Amount:\t\t\t$%.2f\n", tax);
    printf("Total:\t\t\t\t$%.2f\n", total);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please supply the input and output you are expecting, and what did you try to do to debug your program until now?

Comment: I'm not a C coder, but it looks like   while (numberOfDays < 1 ) will run forever since numberofdays never increases.  Infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'd love to help - but we need you to tell us where the problem is, what the problem is, and what you expect to see from the program. Don't let the down-votes get to you, they're only happening because you haven't provided us with what we need to help you. :)

Comment: I don't know where the problem is; but what is supposed to happen is the program is supposed to take the number of days and multiply it by 15 and the number of miles is supposed to be multiplied by .40 if the mileage is under 200. If it is 200 or more, the mileage then gets multiplied by .35. When I do it, it seems to skip over my if statements.

Comment: @Boo92 If you can't pinpoint the location of the error, the first thing you need to do is start debugging. Put print statements into your code to print out variables to see their value, or use an actual debugger to see the full state of your program. Debugging is a crucial skill for programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `numberOfMiles` should be of type `float` you have to exchange the following line

```
scanf("%d", &numberOfMiles);
```

by

```
scanf("%f", &numberOfMiles);
```

or you can set the type to `int`.

--

If you want to avoid an endless loop, exchange

```
} while (numberOfMiles > 1);
```

by

```
} while (numberOfMiles < 1);
```

Btw. why not allow distances that are shorter than a mile?

e.g. by

```
} while (numberOfMiles < 0);
```

For more specific answers, you have to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling your program with gcc gives the following warning:

```
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:21:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘float *’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", &numberOfMiles);
     ^
```

The problem is, that scanf() will store the number entered at the location of numberOfMiles using a binary format used for int variables, but numberOfMiles is a float variable. The integer bit pattern interpreted as float will probably have a very different meaning, or even can be an illegal float value.

Changing the type of numberOfMiles from float to int fixes this problem.

You also should change the second while condition to `while (numberOfMiles < 1)`.

I hope, this helps.

73, Mario